# Remove list within array typescript

Tags: typescript

How do i remove the entire row in this.cols

**Format of this.cols array**

```
this.cols = [
  { field: 'Id', header: 'ID', width: '70px' },
  { field: 'fullName', header: 'Full Name', width: '200px' }
  .....
];

//If does not exist in the access rights list, remove cols
for(var i=0; i<17; i++) {
  if (this.getAccessRights.indexOf('Id') !== -1) {

    //How do i remove the entire row in this.cols if it matches?

  }
}
```

**Expected output of this.cols array**

```
this.cols = [
  { field: 'fullName', header: 'Full Name', width: '200px' }
  .....
];
```

Tried to use remove() but faced errors. Many of the post here are about python which is not useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.cols = this.cols.filter(col => col.field !== 'Id');
```

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array based on the conditional logic within. So what we're doing is saying that if the `field` does not equal `Id`, push that col back into the array.

Comment: you could also use a for loop to break out of the array if there's only one entry with Id for reducing iterative cycles as filter will loop through the ENTIRE array.

Answer (score 0):

```
        const index = this.cols.indexOf(key);
        this.cols.splice(index, 1);
```

Above code gives index of given key in indexOf() method. Then splice() used to remove one elements from given index.